# Which type of fuse should I use with a coil heater?

Tags: fuses

Fast blow or time delay (anti surge) type?  I have read motors require anti surge fuses to permit higher than rated current for short periods during start up.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a slow-blow/anti surge/time delay. The heater's resistance is lower when cold, so there will be a surge of current as well (for a completely different physical reason). However, this depends on a particular application: coil temperature, thermal mass, wiring, what the critical current is.

Comment: Resistance of Nichrome it is not change significally with temperature. Temperature coefficient is only 0.4E-3/degrCelcius for nichr. Compare with copper coefficient 3.9E-3/degrCelcius. Heater is also pure ohmic load.

Comment: Good point about nichrome, but let's if we take let's say 1000K vs 300K, the resistance change is about 30% using your value, which is not huge, but still something to consider. And thanks for the ohmic load info, captain :)